Integrating Visual Basic.NET with the Xrite Ci62 Spectrophotometer: Exploring SDKs, APIs, and Connection Methods
I have my own Visual Basic.NET program, and I want to connect it to the Xrite Ci62 spectrophotometer. Where can I find an SDK or API to facilitate this connection? Alternatively, are there other methods available to establish this connection?
I browsed on the net, but I did'nt find any suitable method or result.
